# parsing regional string language

Tags: python, encoding

I am working on the exel parsing using python.
till now I have worked with english language but when I encounter the regional languages, I am getting the error.

example :

```
IR05 měsíční (monthly)
```

It gives me the error as

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u011b' in position 6: ordinal not in range(128)
```

how I can parse it and I can again write in same language in output files?

my code :

```
for j in val:
    print 'j is - ', j
    str(j).replace("'", "")
```

I am getting error at replace statement.

Comment: Please show us the code you wrote that produced that error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
>>> "IR05 měsíční (monthly)".decode('utf8')
u'IR05 m\u011bs\xed\u010dn\xed (monthly)'
```

which is a unicode version of your original string (which was encoded in utf8).

Now you can compare it to your other string (from the file), which you decode (from utf8 or latin2 or a different format) and you can compare them.

```
>>> 'IR05 m\xecs\xed\xe8n\xed (monthly)'.decode('latin2')
u'IR05 m\u011bs\xed\u010dn\xed (monthly)'
```

now you can compare the two unicode strings:

```
>>> s_utf8 = "IR05 měsíční (monthly)"
>>> s_latin2 = 'IR05 m\xecs\xed\xe8n\xed (monthly)'
>>> s_utf8.decode('utf8') == s_latin2.decode('latin2')
True
```

To write the string into a file, `encode` it again:

```
>>> s = s_utf8.decode('utf8')

>>> filehandle.write(s.encode('utf8'))
```

Comment: actually I wanted to compare "IR05 měsíční (monthly)" with another file in which "IR05 měsíční (monthly)" is written.
when I will decode it, it will give me another format.
how will I check in that format & if its matching then I have to create a file and write "IR05 měsíční (monthly)" in that file

Comment: thanks for nice answer. can you tell me one more thing? If i have decode that statement and now I again want to write that "IR05 měsíční (monthly)" into a file. how i can write that?

Comment: aha so it will again write "IR05 měsíční (monthly)" in file and not as 'IR05 m\u011bs\xed\u010dn\xed (monthly)'

Answer (score 2):

the error may be caused by str(j),
try this:

```
for j in val:
    print 'j is - ', j
    j.replace("'", "")
```

Comment: `j.replace("'", "")` returns an updated version of `j` to… nirvana.